# Parsing multi-level JSON with Codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I'm trying to parse to following JSON into a `tableView` : https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/data/items

I succeeded in parsing the first array, but I'm unable to parse the key "entries"...

Here's my code, with the data structure I defined :

```
import UIKit

struct ItemCategories: Codable {
    var result: [ItemCategory]
}

struct ItemCategory: Codable {
    var label: String
    var entries: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    // empty struct
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let urlString = "https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/data/items"
    var categories = [ItemCategory]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Path of Data"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        parse()
    }

    func parse() {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let jsonItemCategories = try? decoder.decode(ItemCategories.self, from: data) else { return }
        categories = jsonItemCategories.result
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        var categoryName = categories[indexPath.row].label
        if categoryName == "" { categoryName = "Unknown" }
        cell.textLabel?.text = categoryName
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .systemOrange
        let numberOfItemsInCategory = String(categories[indexPath.row].entries.count)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = numberOfItemsInCategory + " items"
        return cell
    }
}
```

The struct Item is empty, because when I try to add variable corresponding to the keys in the JSON, then the whole parsing fail (the tableView displays nothing).

When the struct Item is empty, then the parsing succeed and the tableView is able to display the different categories. It even display the number of items for each "entries" thanks to :

```
let numberOfItemsInCategory = String(categories[indexPath.row].entries.count)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = numberOfItemsInCategory + " items"
```

Can someone explain why ? Ideally I would like to display the content of "entries" when the rows are tapped, but I can't figure out how for the moment.

Thanks for you help :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSYG.jpg)

Comment: `try? ` => **NO!** Instead: `do {... try ... } catch { print("Error: \(error)"}`. It should tell you why the previous attempts in decoding fail. We can't guess what went wrong. So use a `do`/`catch`, and tell us what went wrong exactly.

Comment: Not related but: avoid using `Data(contentsOf:)`, it's blocking the current thread, instead use `URLSession`.

Comment: Parses without problems on my machine.

Comment: For instance, there is a case of `"Ivory Watchstone"` which is "incomplete", with optional values I guess (there are only "name" & "type" properties). It's the last one of all

Comment: @Larme You mean `type` and `text`. The one that is missing is `name`.

Comment: Indeed, I mistyped.

Comment: @Laurent Delorme seems some of object doesn't have `name` & `flags` attributes. so you need to form with optional values on `Item`. the below which is not contains the attributes
```
{
     "type": "Blue Pearl Amulet",
     "text": "Blue Pearl Amulet"
}
```

Comment: Ah yes ! Thank you guys ! Indeed, it seems to work fine when I define all values inside the Item struct as optionals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Laurent Delorme Your Struct `Item` should be like below, try with this,

```
    struct Item: Codable {

    let name: String?

    let type: String?

    let text: String?

    let flags: FlagsRepresentation?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case name
        case type
        case text
        case flags
    }
}

struct FlagsRepresentation: Codable {

    let unique: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case unique
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually get rid of CodingKeys for this case.